# Python or Node for Chat Application

Tags: python, node.js, chat

I intend to start off a new chat web application which allows users to join a chatroom and participate in the chat. I've heard a lot about how Node.js will be perfect for this. Plus, there are a lot of tutorials online that demonstrate building a Node + socket.io chat application. Personally, I have never given Node a shot. I know javascript well enough to work with Jquery and Backbone but I've been avoiding Node due to my preference for Python for web development. What do you guys suggest? Should I try the app in Python ( I have no idea where to get started) or should I spend some time and learn Node?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm personally not a big fan of writing Python, and while I love Node and would recommend giving it a shot sometime, if you already know Python there's no reason you can't use it for this task; you may be interested in checking out [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) or [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/).

I will say that one of the big plusses for using Node.js for evented programming (as compared to doing it in other languages) is that all I/O is asynchronous by default in Node.js. In other environments, you need to make sure you only use non-blocking libraries.

Comment: Twisted was built for this sort of stuff and has a lot of existing functionality that you'd just customize.  I think tornado/gevent/etc would require a bit more work to happen.

If you're looking for the best performance though, I'd want to use Erlang.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is a preferred framework for a chat like application because it is very good with handling conditions which are more data intensive rather than cpu bound. Personally i am a big fan of node.js myself. BUT i am going to step up here and tell you that,

The syntax of node.js for handling asynchronous events becomes a pain once your project grows out of a simple example into a fully grown application. I mean how long will you do this.

```
response.onComplete( function(data) { 
    data.parseJson( function( json ) {
        json.getElement('hoo', function( value ) {
            value.HowDoIEscapeNow()
            .....
```

I do not mean to say anything against node.js but imho its a completely different beast once you go into complexities.

Comment: It is worth noting that a good [asynchronous flow control library](https://github.com/caolan/async) can help you [abstract away some of these pain points](http://nodecasts.net/episodes/5-thinking-asynchronously) nicely.